# Can anyone use System.Windows.Input.ICommand in C++/CLI with VS2012?

Tags: .net, c++-cli, visual-studio-2012, icommand

I'm targeting .Net 4.0 but using VS2012 to support my existing projects. We use commands all over the place for binding in WPF.

It seems the System.Windows namespace is totally missing from the System.dll when I explore it in the External Dependencies.

Am I missing something vital here?

Comment: Which profile are you targeting?  Metro, Client, or full framework?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> It seems the System.Windows namespace is totally missing from the System.dll

That's accurate, that namespace is only present in WPF assemblies.  You'll need to add a reference to PresentationCore.  You'd better add a reference to other common ones as well, just in case, PresentationFramework, WindowsBase and System.Xaml.

Answer (score 0):

[The documentation for `System.Windows.Input.ICommand`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.input.icommand.aspx) lists supported framework profiles:

> .NET Framework    - Supported in: 4, 3.5, 3.0
>
> .NET Framework Client Profile       - Supported in: 4, 3.5 SP1

VS2012 tries to steer you toward Metro app development, but some things aren't available in the Metro profile.